# I tried to use a recursion to solve a so-called tribonacci sequence problem

Tags: python, recursion

The function should be working like
tribonacci([1, 1, 1], 10)-> [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57, 105]

Here is my code

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    if n <= 3:
        return signature[:3]
    else:
        return tribonacci(signature, n-1).append(sum(tribonacci(signature, n-1)[-3:]))
```

It gives me an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'.

I really don't know where the problem is. Can someone show me in detail how the recursion works?

Comment: `.append` doesn't return a new list, it modifies an existing list in place and returns `None`... then you'll have to be wary of a default mutable argument for that `list` and then make sure you recursion criteria is correct... try and see if you can get it working without the first issue and go from there... (there's quite a lot of things to point out here were you're going to potentially trip up and concepts you're going to need to understand...)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your comment really helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JonClements already pointed out in comments, the `append` method does not return a list. It returns `None`, and so the caller will run into an exception when it tries to use that `None` as a list.

As a side note, it is inefficient to make the same recursive call twice. That will make your program do all the same work a second time.

So to resolve these two issues, just do it step-by-step, like this:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    if n <= 3:
        return signature[:3]
    else:
        result = tribonacci(signature, n-1)
        result.append(sum(result[-3:]))
        return result
```

This works, but looks still a bit suspicious, because the `result` list is mutated in each recursion level. This means that in theory all those execution contexts see the mutation done later at a higher level in the recursion tree. This is not an issue in this particular code, but one may consider it is safer to not mutate the list, but return a new list:

```
def tribonacci(signature, n):
    if n <= 3:
        return signature[:3]
    else:
        result = tribonacci(signature, n-1)
        return result + [sum(result[-3:])]

print(tribonacci([1,1,1], 10))
```

If this function is going to be called multiple times with different values for *n* (but same signature), you would get a boost in efficiency if you would implement memoization, so that earlier results can be reused.